# Removing a word from registry string

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to Visual Basic. Can someone please explain me how can i create a string with visual basic. The path that is in registry contains the part that i dont like it

program files\gta san andreas\gta_sa.exe

and i want to make it like

program files\gta san andreas

without gta_sa.exe

i've tried

```
Dim readValue As Object
Dim dobijeno As String
Dim playerName As Object

readValue = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAMP", "gta_sa_exe", Nothing)


dobijeno = readValue

Dim withoutParts As String = Replace(dobijeno, "\gta_sa.exe", "")

TextBox2.Text = readValue

playerName = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAMP", "PlayerName", Nothing)

TextBox1.Text = playerName
```

but it's not working

Comment: You haven't really explained you you decide what should be deleted. If you want to delete that last "\" and everything that follows it, the simplest way is to use `IO.Path.GetDirectoryName` as suggested by @AlastairBrown in a comment on his answer. Also, you should read his answer.

Comment: [Sock puppet / dupe account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6393100/nathaniel)  Read [Ask] and take the [Tour] and perhaps your accounts wont get throttled/Q Banned

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're not doing anything with the replacement result, given that you are only assigning to `withoutParts`, and not subsequently using that variable.  Try this instead:

```
Dim withoutParts As String = Replace(dobijeno, "\gta_sa.exe", "")

TextBox2.Text = withoutParts
```

Comment: Also, it looks like you should possibly be using `Path.GetDirectoryName` rather than `Replace`. That is `Dim withoutParts As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(dobijeno)`